# Intuition of $\limsup_n (X_n - \log n)/\log \log n$, for exponential random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, intuition, limsup-and-liminf

Letting $L = \limsup_n \frac{X_n - \log n}{\log \log n}$, for $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ iid exponentially distributed random variables with rate $1$, I think I am able to show that $L=1$ (*almost everywhere*). Assuming I hadn't made some mistake,it boiled down to a direct application of the Borel-Cantelli lemmas via events $E_n = \left\{\frac{X_n - \log n}{\log \log n} > a\right\}$,
$$
\sum P\left(E_n\right) = \sum P \left(\frac{X_n - \log n}{\log \log n} > a\right) = \sum \frac{1}{n (\log n)^a} = \begin{cases} <\infty & \text{when $a > 1$} \\
= \infty & \text{when $a \leq 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, by BC
$$
\implies P(E_n, \text{i.o}) \equiv P(\limsup_n E_n) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & a > 1 \\
1 & a \leq 1
\end{cases} 
$$
So, as $a \to 1$,
$$
1 = P\left( \limsup_n \left\{ \frac{X_n - \log n}{\log \log n} > 1 \right\} \right) \leq P\left(  \limsup_n \left\{\frac{X_n - \log n}{\log \log n} \right\} \geq 1 \right) = P(L \geq 1)
$$
Similarly, we can end up showing that $P(L > 1) = 0$, giving us the desired result.

My question is a matter of intuition. I (think) I understand the mathematics, but I just cannot wrap my head around how this is at all possible at any level beyond the symbolic manipulation. If I think about sampling/generating exponential deviates $X_n \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} \text{Exp}(1)$, how is it possible that the ratio $\frac{X_n(\omega) - \log n}{\log \log n}$ could possibly approach 1 (for all $\omega$ except those on measure zero sets). I've tried simulating exponential samples and calculating this ratio, keeping $\omega$ fixed (i.e. the PRNG seed fixed) across $n = 1, ..., \texttt{nmax}$. Regardless of how many samples I do, I always end up seeing the behaviour one would expect from, say $\frac{x - \log n}{\log \log n}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Clearly something is either wrong in my calculations above, or something is wrong with my intuition. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you say a little more about how you show the other direction $P(L \le 1)=1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask "how is it possible that the ratio $r_n:=\frac{X_n(\omega) - \log n}{\log \log n}$ could possibly approach 1 (for all $\omega$ except those on measure zero sets)?"
but that is not what limsup means. What is true, and follows from your calculation, is that for every fixed $m$, the sequence $$A_m(N):= \max_{n \in [m,N]} \frac{X_n(\omega) - \log n}{\log \log n}$$   approaches 1 as $N \to \infty$ (for all $\omega$ except those on a set of measure zero). In other words, almost surely, there is a subsequence of $r_n$ that tends to 1, and no subsequence can tend to a higher limit.

Comment: Of course! Thank you, I may have been a little tunnel visioned from my own limited experience with asymptotics